# Como desvincular uma conta do Facebook

Tags: suporte, status-pronto, contas-usuário

O problema é que eu mudei de conta do Facebook e eu faço login por ela, não uso E-mail ou senha para entrar, só o Facebook para entrar no S.O... Como eu coloco outra conta do Facebook nessa conta e/ou coloco para entrar com Email ou senha?

Comment: Em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/24529 você pode adicionar outra conta do Facebook. Para remover a anterior, talvez só com os admins (pelo menos não encontrei como fazer isso sendo moderador).

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No seu perfil, em `Editar perfil & configurações > Meus logins`, estão listados os logins atuais, e você pode adicionar outra conta do Facebook por ali. Não sei se isso substituirá a atual, ou se ambas serão mantidas. Se a antiga for mantida e você ainda quiser removê-la, utilize o [formulário de contato do site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/contact) para solicitar a remoção aos administradores.